# Meteor checkbox always false after Template render

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, checkbox

I have a navbar with 2 entries. One entrie is a checkbox and the other one is a dropdown with a button (I will provide code for that). The `input` has the id `inputMode` and the button `addNewObject`

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li id="editMode">
               <a href="#">
                   <label><input type="checkbox" value="Edit Mode" id="inputMode">Edit Mode</label>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                   aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Scenegraph <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><div style="text-align:center;">
                        <input id="addNewObject" type="button" class="btn-success" value="Add Object">
                    </div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

For each of the id's i have `click` function's.

```
'click #inputMode': function (event, tmpl) {
    let isChecked = $("#inputMode").is(":checked");
    if (isChecked) {
       // do something
    } else {
      //do something
    }
},
'click #addNewObject': function (ev) {

    Helper.initSceneGraph();

}
```

So the thing is when i click the button `addNewObject` the navbar gets rerendered, like this:

```
static initSceneGraph() {
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
        Template.sceneGraph.helpers({
            sceneObjects: Application.getInstance().scene.sceneObjects,
            isAudio: function (obj) {
                return obj._soundPath;
            }
        });
    }
    UI.render(Template.sceneGraph, document.body);
}
```

So after the `initSceneGraph` the checkbox `inputMode` doesnt change. That means visually it changes, but intern it always stays the same. For example`console.log($("#inputMode").is(":checked");` is either ALWAYS false or ALWAYS true, depending if it was true or false BEFORE clicking the button.

I hope someone can help me out with this!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jquery before or after the render?

```
'click #addNewObject': function (ev) {
    $('#inputMode').prop('checked', true);
    Helper.initSceneGraph();
}
```